# Using a Version Control System on a Shared Network Drive at Work

Tags: git, github, pycharm, intellij-plugin

I am trying to set up a version control system at work to manage python code among multiple collaborators (ideally, the VCS would be integrated into IntelliJ PyCharm).

I am familiar with GitHub, which I have played around with. But I am leery of putting the intellectual property (code) of the company on GitHub servers (even if it is a paid, private repository). I would like to basically take advantage of Git VCS, but instead of storing repositories on GitHub online servers, I would instead like these repositories to be on our the Shared Windows Drive @ work. Is it possible to do this with Git?

Here is the set up:
Each user has a local drive and access to the shared drive
I want each user to have a local repository on their local drives, which they can push to the 'master' repository on the shared drive (pending checking the code differences and approvals, which I currently do on the GitHub website via 'pull request').

Does that make sense?  I can't seem to find any tutorials / documentation on how to achieve this!

Thank you!

Comment: No, it doesn't make any sense. Try to search "how to setup git server"

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly use git without github.

Placing the origin repo on a shared drive is one option, but it has some disadvantages.  (To avoid confusion, by the way, its a good idea to refer to the source repository as *origin*; in git terminology, *master* is the default branch.)

You will still need each developer to clone the repo, and they should use `file://` URL's to clone it.  (Just using the path will work, but may cause additional issues.)  So for example

```
git clone file://server/share/path/to/repo
```

Another option is to internally host a server that supports git.  You could use something like GitLab.  Or you could host it in TFS.  Or there are others...  (You also *can* just put it on a web server, but again this won't get you advanced workflow features etc.)

Comment: this worked perfectly, thank you!  Is there any way to password protect the origin repository.  In addition, is it possible to make that repository read-only, and only changable via a GIT Push (requiring approvals of all diffs)?

Comment: If you've just decided to put the repo on a share, then your options to control access are limited.  Workflow controls (approval processes, etc.) really will require something like a local GitLab instance, or TFS, etc.  I'd start by looking into "pull requests" or "merge requests".  For a repo on a share, at best you can provide course access control with fs permissions.